# airflow kubernetes default setup ERROR: relation "log" does not exist at character 13

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, airflow-2.x

I deployed the [default helm chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html) for airflow 2.

The postgres pod is reporting an error:

```
ERROR:  relation "log" does not exist at character 13
```

This appears after this statement:

```
INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) 
VALUES ('2022-03-30T12:31:33.329502+00:00'::timestamptz, NULL, NULL, 'cli_check'
, NULL, 'airflow', '{"host_name": "airflow2-scheduler-64d6cdd59c-cns4m", 
"full_command": "[''/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow'', ''db'', ''check'']"}') 
RETURNING log.id
```

However, if I just run the exact same statement after logging into PG through pgAdmin, the statement runs successfully.

Should I ignore this error?  Do I need to do something to fix/avoid the error?

I did find [this issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/18327) reported but with no solution.

Worth adding that the pod looks healthy despite the log showing that error.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run below command

`airflow upgrade db`

in order to fill up missing tables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).